# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0x0)

Tags: c++, xcode, algorithm

I'm making Dijikstra algorithm in c++ (XCode). 
I'm getting exc_bad_access code=1 at that moment:

```
 for (k=0; k<M; k++){
    input>>i>>j>>V;
    Graf[i][j] = V;
}
```

Whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int min(int[]);                             
int **Graf;                                 
int *Label;                                 
int *Active;                                

int i, j, k;
int Start, N, M, V, Last;

using namespace std;

int min(int array[]) {
    int min, k, min_pos = -1;
    min = 32767;


    for (k=0; k<M; k++) {
        if (array[k] < min && Active[k] == 1){
            min = array[k];
            min_pos = k;
            }
        }

    return min_pos;
}




int main(){

    ifstream input ("input.txt");           



    input>>N>>M>>Start>>Last;

     if (!input){
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    Graf = new int *[N];
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        Graf[i] = new int [N];
    }


    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            Graf[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    Label = new int [N];


    Active = new int [N];


    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        Label[i] = 0;
        Active[i] = 0;
    }


    for (k=0; k<M; k++){
        input>>i>>j>>V;
        Graf[i][j] = V;
    }



    for (i=0; i<M; i++){
        Label[i] = 32767;
        Active[Start] = 1;
    }

    Label[Start] = 0;
    i = Start;
    do
    {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            if (Graf[i][j] != 0 && Label[j] > Label[i] + Graf[i][j]){
                Active[j] = 1;
                Label[j] = Label[i] + Graf[i][j];
            }
            Active[i] = 0;
            i=min(Label);
    }
    while (i != -1);
    cout << Label[Last] << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I'm looking for a mistake for some days, but can't find.

Input.txt 
5 9 0 4
0 0 5 2 4 0
0 0 0 7 0 6
5 0 0 9 1 15
2 7 9 0 0 12
4 0 1 0 0 8
0 6 15 12 8 0

Comment: You should be using `std::min_element`.

Comment: Too many `new`s. Why not `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is in your input file: you read i and j and use it to access your arrays, without verifying that these value are within expected boundaries.

For instance, if you improve your questioned code with an error message, like:

```
for (k=0; k<M; k++){
    input>>i>>j>>V;
    if (i>=N || j>=N) {
        cerr << "Bad Input for k="<<k<<": "<<i<<","<<j<<","<<V<<endl;
        continue;
    }
    //assert(i<N && j<N);  variant if you don't care for the values
    Graf[i][j] = V;
}
```

You'll get the following results:

```
Bad Input for k=3: 7,0,6
Bad Input for k=4: 5,0,0
Bad Input for k=5: 9,1,15
Bad Input for k=6: 2,7,9
```